# Compilation failing - no #include - boost

Tags: c++, boost, include, g++

I'm trying to compile a third-party library, but g++ is complaining about the following line:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MessageConsumer> MessageConsumerPtr;
```

The strange thing is, there is no `#include` directive in the file - and it is clearly supposed to be this way; there are about 60 files with the same (or very similar) issues. Clearly if there was an `#include` directive referencing the relevant boost header this would compile cleanly.

My question is: how can I get g++ to somehow automagically find the relevant symbol (in all instances of this issue, it is a namespace that can't be found - usually `std::` or `boost::`) by either automatically processing the relevant header (or some other mechanism).

Thanks.

**Edit**

My current g++ call looks like:

```
g++ -fPIC -O3 -DUSING_PCH -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/boost -I./ -c MessageInterpreter.cpp -o MessageInterpreter.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-include` command line option:

```
g++ -include boost/shared_ptr.hpp ...
```

From the man page:

> -include file
>              Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared as the first line of
>              the primary source file.  However, the first directory searched for
>              file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the
>              directory containing the main source file.  If not found there, it
>              is searched for in the remainder of the "#include "..."" search
>              chain as normal.

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it - now I have to go through and find all the 30 odd missing includes...

Answer (score 1):

Create your own wrapper .h file that includes the boost .h and then the broken .h .

Or (very fragile) ensure that you precede every use of the broken .h with boost .h .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the third-party library is designed in such a way that you should always include a certain "main" header file in order to get the dependencies right.

Otherwise, you can add `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` before including the third-party header file that is giving the error message.